# jQuery datepicker language (Localization) How to change between languages

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter, jquery-ui

I'm trying to set the location to my jQuery UI calender, but it doesn't work.

Those are my links:

**Header View File:** header1.php

```
<head>  
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url("assets/testelib/jquery-ui.min.css"); ?>">

<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url("assets/lib/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"); ?>"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url("assets/lib/datepicker/jquery-ui.min.js"); ?>"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url("assets/lib/datepicker/jquery-ui.js"); ?>"></script>
```

**Those are the example files used in the jQuery online example that I did download and I'm trying to generate the result.**
https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url("assets/lib/datepicker/jquery-1.12.4.js"); ?>"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url("assets/lib/datepicker/jquery-ui-1.12.1.js"); ?>"></script>
```

**Languages downloaded now right from:**
*https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/tree/master/ui/i18n*

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url("assets/lib/datepicker/i18n/datepicker-de.js"); ?>"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url("assets/lib/datepicker/i18n/datepicker-fr.js"); ?>"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url("assets/lib/datepicker/i18n/datepicker-pt-BR.js"); ?>"></script>
<head>
```

**and the VIEW file:** register1.php

```
<body>

<script>
$(function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker($.datepicker.regional["de"]);       
    // Event onChange
    $("#locale").on("change", function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker("option", $.datepicker.regional[$(this).val()]);
});
});
</script>

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker">&nbsp;
 <select id="locale">
<option value="de" selected="selected">Deutsch (German)</option>                
<option value="">English</option>
<option value="fr">French (Fran&ccedil;ais)</option>
<option value="pt-BR">Portugues BR</option>
</select></p>

<body/>
```

What am I doing wrong please? The calendar shows only the date and etc with the default language (English).

Answer (score 0):

This was fun, not having used this before.

I ended on going to https://jqueryui.com/download/ and grabbed the 1.12.1 jquery version with everything just for fun later...

So from that download I grabbed the jquery.js and jquery-ui.min.js and put those in my assets folder (see the paths I used, but yours will be fine).

My Test View File - Call it what you like...

```
<script src="<?= base_url('assets/datepicker/jquery.js'); ?>"></script>
<script src="<?= base_url('assets/datepicker/jquery-ui.min.js'); ?>"></script>

<script src="<?= base_url('assets/datepicker/datepicker-de.js'); ?>"></script>
<script src="<?= base_url('assets/datepicker/datepicker-fr.js'); ?>"></script>
<script src="<?= base_url('assets/datepicker/datepicker-pt-BR.js'); ?>"></script>


<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker">&nbsp;
    <select id="locale">
        <option value="de" selected="selected">Deutsch (German)</option>
        <option value="en">English</option>
        <option value="fr">French (Fran&ccedil;ais)</option>
        <option value="pt-BR">Portugues BR</option>
    </select>
</p>

<script>
    let domDatePicker = $("#datepicker");
    $(function () {
        domDatePicker.datepicker(); // <<< it appears this needs to be called first.
        domDatePicker.datepicker("option", $.datepicker.regional["de"]);
        $("#locale").on("change", function () {
            console.log($(this).val());
            domDatePicker.datepicker("option", $.datepicker.regional[$(this).val()]);
        });
    });
</script>
```

FYI - I assign the DOM element to a variable and then refer to it... which is where `let domDatePicker = $("#datepicker");` comes from.

From what I experienced (my tinkering) it appears that you need to initialise the datepicker first. i.e. `domDatePicker.datepicker();` or else nothing appears until you make a selection which seems odd, when using Google Chrome on Linux.

Anyway hope that gets you closer to something working wonderfully well.

Comment: Hello @TimBrownlaw, Thank you for the light, but that's not still the answer. Interesting thing is, with this script, **the calendar catch the browser language automatically**. i use the browser in pt-BR. When i change the select, for _DE_, _FR_ or _EN_, the calendar continues showing in _pt-BR_.

What should be another alternative : )?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Did you try the sample test code all on its own with nothing else linked/included etc.